# Infinite collection of homeophisms from $S^1\times S^1$ to $S^1\times S^1$ that are not homotopic.

Tags: general-topology

While studying for my topology exam I tried to come up with a solution of the following problem.

Let $X=S^1\times S^1$. Give (with proof) an infinite collection of homeomorphisms $f_i:X\to X$ such for all $i\neq j$ we have that $f_i$ and $f_j$ are not homotopic.

I was thinking about the identity map and the map that cuts the torus and twists the right part and put it together. Like

[image]

Can someone tell me if this is a good approach, if not give an example?

The next thing I really have a problem with is how to proof that these maps are not homotopic.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know an infinite collection of automorphisms of the fundamental group of $S^1\times S^1$?

Comment: The problem is that my algebraic knowledge isn't that well. The fundamentalgroup of the torus is $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: Indeed, it is. ${}$

Comment: The generators for $\mathbb{Z}$ are only -1 and 1 and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ has 4 generators. So the cardinality of Aut($\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$) is at most that of $S_4$. It seems like there is only a finite collection of automorphisms.

Comment: there is no reason why an automorphism has to permute a fixed generating set...

Answer (score 0):

First note that it is easy to distinguish selfmaps of the torus by means of the fundamental group.  Thus, rather than considering selfmaps of $X$, consider maps $S^1\to X$.  These are classified up to homotopy by $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}^2$, an infinite group.  Now to obtain infinitely many selfmaps of $X$, consider the projection to the first factor $X\to S^1$ and compose it with the maps $S^1\to X$ as above.

If you need specifically homeomorphisms, consider the action of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on the plane.  This defines a self-map of the torus by passing to the quotient $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$.  By examining the action on the first factor, you can similarly show that there are infinitely many of these that are not homotopic.

Comment: That won't get self-homeomorphisms, will it? Since $X\to S^1$ is not $1-1$...

Comment: I wasn't finished posting my comment :-)

Comment: Well, OP specifically asks for homeomorphism, so the first paragraph strikes me as unhelpful.